# Passing an array of constructor arguments through hardhat-etherscan in CLI

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, constructor, cli

Here is the code that I used to deploy this contract to the Rinkeby network.

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  // Hardhat always runs the compile task when running scripts with its command
  // line interface.
  //
  // If this script is run directly using `node` you may want to call compile
  // manually to make sure everything is compiled
  // await hre.run('compile');

  // We get the contract to deploy
  const paySplit = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("paySplit");
  const paysplit = await paySplit.deploy(["0x16DD346Aa1483264DBb0Dde64235081C867fb3f2", "0x6d6257976bd82720A63fb1022cC68B6eE7c1c2B0"], [35, 65]);

  await paysplit.deployed();

  console.log("paySplit deployed to:", paysplit.address);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

As you can see I pass my constructor arguments through the deploy function as so. I am used to just copy and pasting this in my `npx hardhat verify` command. When I run the command

`npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby 0x0ed0074898c451E8379F6B1C763D5426beAcD511 (["0x16DD346Aa1483264DBb0Dde64235081C867fb3f2", "0x6d6257976bd82720A63fb1022cC68B6eE7c1c2B0"], [35, 65]`

it gives me an error.

`ParserError: Line | 1 |  … network rinkeby 0x0ed0074898c451E8379F6B1C763D5426beAcD511 (["0x16DD3 … |                                                                 ~ | Missing type name after '['.`

It seems that there is something that I need to do to pass the the array containing my addresses. However, I have no idea what I should do. What can I do to pass these arrays in the hardhat command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can actually create an `arguments.js` script that basically allows you to plugin the same arguments as you do in your deploy script. You just have to make sure to use the flag `--constructor-args scripts/arguments.js`

Here is the `arguments.js` script:

```
module.exports = [
    ["0x16DD346Aa1483264DBb0Dde64235081C867fb3f2", "0x6d6257976bd82720A63fb1022cC68B6eE7c1c2B0"], [35, 65]
]
```

[Reference to docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan#complex-arguments)